# How to update values in p5 sketch based on react states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods, react-props, p5.js

To say it simply, I'm trying to pass down props from react component to a p5 sketch. I'm able to pass down props from React to the sketch(hopefully), but unable to change the values in the sketch through the props I passed.

```js
const sketch = (p) => {
    let cnv, speedX=2, speedY=4;
    
    p.setup = function () {
      //setup
    }
    
    p.draw = function (){
      //In draw we are trying to draw animate a bouncing ball. Main code to do so is as follows:
      
      posX += speedX;
      posY += speedY;
    }
    
    //based on the props we want to change the speed of the ball.
    p.changeSpeed = function(props){
        if(props.speed !== speedY){
            speedX = props.speed - 2;
            speedY = props.speed;
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the React code, where we declare p5 sketch as well as pass down the props.

```js
function P5() {
    
    const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(4);
    const p5ContainerRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        // On component creation, instantiate a p5 object with the sketch and container reference 
        const p5Instance = new p5(sketch, p5ContainerRef.current);

        // On component destruction, delete the p5 instance
        return () => {
            p5Instance.remove();
        }
    }, []);

  return (
    <div>
            <div className="canvas" ref={p5ContainerRef} speed={speed} />
            
            <input type="range" min="3" max="6" value={speed} onChange={(e) => setSpeed(e.target.value)}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default P5
```

Where am I getting wrong? Once the setup is done, draw function is called repeatedly~ infinitely. Do I need to call changeSpeed() method inside of draw?

```js
p.draw = function(){
  //rest of the code
  
  changeSpeed();
}
```

I am out of ideas at this point. Any help is appreciated.

***Thank you***

Comment: "Props" are a React concept. In vanilla JS, it's just arguments/parameters. I thought I just responded to this question or a similar one yesterday, but what values are you trying to update here? Call `changeSpeed` if that helps your app logic, otherwise don't. `props.speed` won't be visible in p5 unless you either pass that as an argument to a closure or class constructor that wraps  the sketch, or you nest the sketch inside the component.